# MiniProfiler Throwing Unexpected Token with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfiler on an MVC 4 app. We have a view being rendered in a modal (using the Colorbox jquery plugin). That view then has a partial view in it with an ajax form that looks like this:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("<action name>", "<controller name>", new {area="<area name>"}, new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "modal-body",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }))
{
    <html for form here>
}
```

When we submit the form it returns the same partial view to overwrite this whole section on the view. When it's posted MiniProfiler throws an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

This happens in this function:

```
var jQueryAjaxComplete = function (e, xhr, settings) {
            if (xhr) {
                // should be an array of strings, e.g. ["008c4813-9bd7-443d-9376-9441ec4d6a8c","16ff377b-8b9c-4c20-a7b5-97cd9fa7eea7"]
                var stringIds = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-MiniProfiler-Ids');
                if (stringIds) {
                    var ids = typeof JSON != 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(stringIds) : eval(stringIds);
                    fetchResults(ids);
                }
            }
        };
```

It's expecting to a json array of guids, but instead it's getting the array twice, like this:

"["6de0e02c-e694-4d8a-ac22-ea6a847efe0e","970f6640-fe5b-45d9-bf59-c916b665458d"], ["6de0e02c-e694-4d8a-ac22-ea6a847efe0e","970f6640-fe5b-45d9-bf59-c916b665458d"]"

This causes it to puke when it tries to parse the array. I'm not sure why the array is getting duplicated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you see in your Developer Tools within your browser... does the response from the server reflect those unexpected results or does it look correct?

Comment: The comment in miniprofiler function says it should get something like: ["008c4813-9bd7-443d-9376-9441ec4d6a8c","16ff377b-8b9c-4c20-a7b5-97cd9fa7eea7"] but in my case it's getting "["6de0e02c-e694-4d8a-ac22-ea6a847efe0e","970f6640-fe5b-45d9-bf59-c916b665458d"], ["6de0e02c-e694-4d8a-ac22-ea6a847efe0e","970f6640-fe5b-45d9-bf59-c916b665458d"]"

Comment: I am not much aware of MiniProfiler but there is bug there which might related.. http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=99

Answer (score 0):

This a miniprofiler bug https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/pull/5

Wait for next update.